# C++ Faster char array compare

Tags: c++, arrays, string, performance, compare

---

What I am trying to do is to find a faster way to do the same program but execute faster.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
int main ()

    {
        int br=0, c, n, b, e, i, q, g;
        char t[7000], a[7000];
        scanf("%d" ,&n);
        for (g=0; g<n; g++)  // number of test cases
        {
            scanf ("%7000s",&t);
            c=strlen(t);
            scanf ("%7000s",&a);
            b=strlen(a);
            for (i=0; i<b; i++)  // comparing them
            {
                for (q=0; q<c; q++)
                {
                    if (a[i]==t[q] && a[i]!='\0' && t[q]!='\0')
                    {
                    br++;a[i]='\0';t[q]='\0';
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("%d \n", br);
            br=0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

## The program itself does this:

1st input: Number of test cases
2nd: You must input A array and B array for every test case
the program must check if there are any common letters from B to match with A and if there   are, to output how much they are.

```
Example input: 
2
qwerty
abc
abcde
bcex
Output: 
0
3
```

What I need is to make it run faster.
Any help is apreciated. :)

Comment: Just for interest..Did you ever try to input 7000 chars from console?

Comment: Nope :D why ? is this someway related to the problem ?

Comment: Remove `&` when you use `%s` to scan string e.g. `scanf ("%7000s", &t);` should be `scanf ("%7000s", t);`. By the way your code more looks time C rather than C++.

Comment: Isn't this the problem from codechef February challenge? The contest is still on and you can't get solutions like this..

Comment: My teacher gave it as my homework. I don't know ..

Comment: Use a lookup table, which will get you to O(N+M), where N and M are the lengths of your two strings respectively. If you can get it faster than that, you should be doing my job.

Comment: You can tell you teacher ambiguity is the devils workshop for programming exercises, btw. What answer do you expect for `abbcccdddd` and `aaabbc`? Is it 3, 4, 6, or something else? Why?

Comment: @user3312862 for example you shouldn't use scanf and printf in C++ use cin, cout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In keeping with the mantra of C code with C++ headers, this is the lookup table method I referred to. The resulting complexity is O(N+M) where N and M are the lengths of your respective strings. Since it is a foregone conclusion each char in each string must be visited at least once (and in this case no more than that), I'm somewhat comfortable in suggesting algorithm-wise it would be hard to do better without reaching into the asm bag-o-tricks.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (n-- >0)
    {
        char a[7000], b[7000];
        if (scanf ("%7000s", a) == 1 && scanf ("%7000s", b) == 1)
        {
            unsigned short table[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {0};
            unsigned int answer = 0;
            const char *p;

            for (p=b; *p; ++table[(unsigned char)*p++]);
            for (p=a; *p; ++p)
            {
                if (table[(unsigned char)*p])
                {
                    --table[(unsigned char)*p];
                    ++answer;
                }
            }

            printf("%u\n", answer);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @user3312862 I don't need it. As I said, it will be one of those two answers. Should be simple enough to clarify.

Comment: when I remove the line:
`table[(unsigned char)*p] = 0;`
it isn't working well for the example in out ...

Comment: Let me explain, maybe it's my fault that I didn't explained correctly.
We are matching the letters from the second string and if they exist in the first we add ++answer :)

Comment: I hope that was correct, because the code was changed to match the second of the two options presented. It will be up for a little while if you want to look. [**See It Live**](http://ideone.com/P9mGUC)

Comment: @Block4o Explain *why*.

Comment: The wording in this question is absolutely dreadful. I think the code as-is now (see changes above) will do what you want. The second string populate the unique list, each entry with a counter for number of occurrences. As the first string is walked, frequencies are consumed from the table until they reach zero, at which point they non longer contribute to the answer. *I have absolutely no idea whatsoever if that is what is really needed at this point*, but I certainly hope it is, as I'm done for the night. Best of luck for you.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to make a hash of every character in both strings. Each character corresponds to an ASCII value. Store count of each character in some other array for both strings. Compare the hash arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Place your input in two sorted containers of `char` eg [deques](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/). Then perform a [set intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) and measure the size of the result. This should drop the complexity significantly

**EDIT**

example of ammending a sorted deque with user input

```
void addChar2Deque(char newChar, std::deque<char> &sorted_cont) {
    sorted_cont.insert(std::lower_bound(sorted_cont.begin(), sorted_cont.end(), newChar), newChar);
}
```

If you can only have your input in prefetched data, then you can just sort that data, eg for array of `char` sized N

```
std::sort(prefetched_data, prefetched_data+N);
```

In any case you'll end up with two containers (deque or C array) that can be compared with `std::set_intersection`

```
std::vector<char> result;
std::set_intersection(std::begin(cont1), std::end(cont1),
    std::begin(cont2), std::end(cont2), std::back_inserter(result));
return result.size();
```